# Chart.js "display:none" Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jsfiddle, chart.js

I have been looking around the threads for a solution of this, and I have tried a few different hacks - to no avail. A lot of people were having problems using chart JS nested in Tabs of some sort. FOr my project I am putting 3 or more charts into a category in which can be selected via selection>option. When the user selects the option I want those charts to show. You can see the logic in the JSFiddle below. I know I can definitely shorten my code up a little bit but that is for another time. For now I just want these charts to show! As a test, you can comment out the css of `display:none;` and you will see the chart functions the way it is supposed to but including it initially is what I would like to do, and still have it function. Anyone else have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikemanusama/0ogx35ot/11/

Comment: I have the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872504/chartjs-not-rendering-when-div-hidden

Here is the issue https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/29

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue is but if you add `$(".surveyResults").hide();` inside of your function instead of adding display:none; in the CSS it will work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ogx35ot/12/

Comment: Ughhh...Thank you. x10

Comment: @MikeManusama If this answer solved your problem you should accept it.

Comment: Nah, with this hidden content is shows up for a second until script loads.